# Error 404 trying to get metadata from an AWS EC2 instance with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get the user-data from an AWS EC2 instance with PHP using:

```
<?php
$instance_id = file_get_contents("http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/user-data");
?>
```

However, I keep getting:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/user-data): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in ... while reading response header from upstream, client: ..., server: ..., request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"...
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was an easy error - that cost me a lot of time -.

The path should be:

```
http://instance-data/latest/user-data
```

Comment: It's always the simple things that can cost the most of time. But you can always be sure that `404 Not Found in` means it cannot be found at the specified path: period. :)

Comment: To note, I don't think `instance-data` is officially supported as a hostname. I think the IP `169.254.169.254` is still the recommended address for instance metadata. (See last post of https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=536813) If this has changed please let me know.